# Image visible according to query boolean in Access 2013 Form

Tags: ms-access-2013

Hy,

I'm on Access 2013 Form.

I would like to show and hide this image according to the value of a boolean (ET1_EDD) coming from a sql query.

I checked, the value of this boolean is correctly returned on my form, but I think that I can not write my condition correctly.

[image]

I try

```
=VraiFaux([ET1_EDD]=Faux;[Bnt_UnValid_EDD].[Visible]=Vrai;[Bnt_UnValid_EDD].[Visible]=Faux)
```

or

```
=[Bnt_UnValid_EDD].[Visible]=VraiFaux([ET1_EDD]=Faux;Vrai;Faux)
```

And I tried with 'True' or 'False' / 1 or 0 / 'Vrai' or 'Faux' ... same result, it does not work
Someone would have any idea?

Comment: Wrong place in `SourceControl`you assign the picture with a record,, you need a `Form_Open`event (vba) where you assign`Me.[Bnt_UnValid_EDD].[Visible]= Not Me.[ET1_EDD]`.

Comment: Thank you so much ComputerVersteher, but this image exist for each line of the query list item, and i don't anderstand how i can do that for each line.